# prove that ${1\over x^2}$ is not uniformly continuous in $(0,\infty)$

Tags: calculus

how can I prove that ${1\over x^2}$ is not uniformly continuous in $(0,\infty)$ with the negation of uniformly continuous function? ( f is not uniformly continuous function if $\exists {\epsilon_0 \gt 0}$ so that $\forall {\delta \gt 0}  \exists x,y\in (0,\infty), {|x-y|\lt\delta}\Rightarrow|{1\over x^2}-{1\over y^2}|\ge\epsilon_0$ I would appreciate your help

Comment: Whereas the difference between numbers on the $x-axis$ get smaller and smaller, the difference of their image gets much larger and much larger. What does this mean in regards to your problem?

Comment: Hint: the problem is rather near $0$ than near $+\infty$. What sequence does that suggest, if you were to pick one to contradict uniform continuity?

Comment: I think I need to give a fix $\epsilon_0$ like $\epsilon_0={1\over 2}$ and then i need to prove that $|{1\over x^2}-{1\over y^2}|\ge{1\over 2}$ am I right?

Comment: You can even fix $\epsilon_0=1$. What will really make your life easier is to consider $x=1/n$ and $y=1/(n+1)$ for large enough $n$, for a given $\delta$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $f$ is continuous on $(a,b)\text { is uniformly continuous }\Leftrightarrow$ $\lim_{x\downarrow  a}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\uparrow b}f(x)$ exists

Answer (score 1):

$(1)$ Call two sequences in $\Bbb R$ cofinal if $|x_n-y_n|\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

$(2)$ Prove a function is uniformly continuous iff it maps cofinal sequences to cofinal sequences.

$(3)$ Find a pair of cofinal sequences that are not mapped to cofinal sequences by your function.

Comment: what is cofinal sequ?????????????????????

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$ , $x_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $y_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$.For given ${\epsilon_0 = 1/2}$,  and any $\delta \gt 0$,we can find a $N∈\mathbb{Z}$ so that $|x_{N}-y_{N}|<\delta$ and $|f(x_N)-f(y_{N})|=1>\epsilon_0$.Hence $f(x)$ is not uniformly continuous in$(0,+\infty)$.